# Issue sorting array

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'm new to c#. I have an array values like this

```
id    name      subject    marks
1     jhone       math     60
2     smith       science  50
3     clark       math     90
1     jhone       science  80
3     clark       science  56
1     jhone       ecnomics 75
2     smith       math     40
3     clark       ecnomics 99
```

first I want to sort array like this

```
id    name      subject    marks
1     jhone       math     60
1     jhone       science  80
1     jhone       ecnomics 75

2     smith       science  50
2     smith       math     40

3     clark       math     90
3     clark       science  56
3     clark       ecnomics 99
```

`array.sort` command working ok

now I want to concatenate these values and answer show like this

```
1,jhone,math 60,science 80,ecnomics 75
3,clark,math 90,science 56,ecnomics 99
```

Remember I'd like to not display content because id 2 have 2 subjects..his economics result is pending..so only show the above two lines in the result.

thanks in advance

Comment: The 'please solve my problem' might rub some people the wrong way... 'Please **help me** solve my problem' is what you should aim for.

Comment: Can you post your current code?

Comment: *"his economics result is pending"* - so because he doesn't have a result in economics he is not to be displayed?

Comment: How is your data stored? id/name/subject etc in a struct? etc. Post some code

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not even sure what you're going for here, so if I'm off-base please provide a little more detail in to what you're trying to accomplish.

With that being said, using LINQ you can do this fairly easily:

First I start out with the object you're using. I've named it `Foo`, but this is (what appears to be) the structure you've supplied:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Subject { get; set; }
    public Int32 Marks { get; set; }
}
```

Next, you can go through and group and sort by the ID, then pull the results that match that grouping:

```
var results = from b in Bar                     // Bar is my list of "Foo"s
              orderby b.Id ascending            // order it by ID
              group b by b.Id into grp       // then group them
              select new
              {
                  ID = grp.Key,                 // re-grab the ID
                  Foo = grp
              };
```

Now we go through the `results` and filter by the "has three options" you seem to be specifying. This is where you may need to be more diligent on how you determine a result is "outputable".

```
List<String> concat = new List<String>();
foreach (var result in results)
{
    if (result.Foo.Count() == 3) // has three options?
    {
        List<String> vals = new List<string>();
        vals.AddRange(new[]{ result.ID.ToString(), result.Foo.ElementAt(0).Name });

        foreach (var foo in result.Foo)
            vals.Add(String.Format("{0} {1}", foo.Subject, foo.Marks));
        concat.Add(String.Join(",", vals.ToArray()));
    }
}
```

And now `concat` has the items:

```
1,jhone,math 60,science 80,economics 75
3,clark,math 90,science 56,economics 99
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get all the entries with certain values like this by using a Linq query.  For instance,

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (String n in studentNames)
{
    IEnumerable<Record> query = from r in studentArray where r.Name == nameIter select r;
    sb.Append(r.id.ToString() + "," + r.name);
    foreach (Record r in query)
    {
        sb.Append("," + r.className);
        sb.Append(" " + r.score)
    }
    sb.Append("\n");
}
```

You had some other requirement to not show students with only 2 records but it wasn't very clear to me what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've sorted the array, go through it sequentially, building a `List` for each student. When the student number changes, only output if all subjects are covered.

Assuming you have this class:

```
class StudentGrade
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Subject { get; private set; }
    public int Marks { get; private set; }
    // Constructor and other things go here
}
```

And you have an array of those that you've sorted:

```
StudentGrade[] Grades;
```

Now, you want to output a line for each student that has all three grades:

```
List<StudentGrade> l = new List<StudentGrade>();
int LastId = -1;
foreach (var grade in Grades)
{
    if (grade.Id == LastId || LastId == -1)
    {
        // add this item to the list
        l.Add(grade);
    }
    else
    {
        // New student. Output data for previous student.
        if (l.Count == 3)
        {
            // output this student.
        }
        else
        {
            // student not output because not all grades are in.
        }
        LastId = grade.Id;
        l.Clear();
        l.Add(grade);
    }
}
// Check last student
if (l.Count == 3)
{
    // output last student
}
else
{
    // don't output because not all grades are in
}

}
```